# Подсчитать сумму заказа исходя из цены и количества в каждом поле

Tags: javascript

Уважаемые знатоки, помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Бьюсь уже пол дня, не могу добиться чтобы при увеличении количества в поле input автоматически количество перемножалось на цену и выводило результат.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  var inp;
  myDiv.onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || event
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.value == '+') {
      inp = target.previousSibling.previousSibling;
      if (parseInt(inp.value) < 5) {
        inp.value = parseInt(inp.value) + 1;  
      }
    } else if (target.value == '-') {
      inp = target.nextSibling.nextSibling;
      if (parseInt(inp.value) > 1) {
        inp.value = parseInt(inp.value) - 1;
      }
    }  
 var znachenie = document.getElementById('inp').value;
 var prise = document.getElementById('price').textContent;
 var totalPriceProduct = prise * znachenie;
 document.getElementById('total_price').innerHTML = totalPriceProduct;
 document.getElementById('total_price_post').value = totalPriceProduct;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
<p><span id="price">500</span> грн.
<input type="button" value="-">
<input type="text" id="inp" size="1" value="1">
<input type="button" value="+">
<span id="total_price">500</span>
<input id="total_price_post" type="text" value="500"></p>
<p><span id="price">500</span> грн.
<input type="button" value="-">
<input type="text" id="inp" size="1" value="1">
<input type="button" value="+">
<span class="total_price">500</span>
<input type="text" value="500"></p>
<p><span id="price">500</span> грн.
<input type="button" value="-">
<input type="text" id="inp" size="1" value="1">
<input type="button" value="+">
<span class="total_price">500</span>
<input type="text" value="500"></p>
</div>
<div class="summa_result"></div>
```

Comment: Начнём с того, что вёрстка неправильная. `id` не должен дублироваться.

Comment: А как я выведу в цикле эти поля с уникальными id? Можно конечно извратится, но это не выход. Увеличение input поля прекрасно работает. Или я не правильно понял комментарий?

Comment: @crosh это выход. Текущий код не может работать никак. `id` должны быть уникальными. Расскажите, что вы хотите получить кодом `var znachenie = document.getElementById('inp').textContent;`? К какому инпуту вы обращаетесь?

Comment: В том то и дело что я понимаю что это х..ня, потому что я получается обращаюсь ко всем инпутам, точнее к самому первому, а нужно обратится к определенному. И я понимаю что уникальный id легко решает эту проблему. Но я подозреваю что есть простое и нормальное решение без изменения id.

Comment: Anton Shchyrov, а тем нехитрым действием, что вы указали, я ничего не получу потому что я должен брать инфу из value а не считывать между тегов. Это моя ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать подсчёт, основываясь на вёрстке, но это сильно неправильно - чуть изменить и всё полетит.
Лучше сделать базу в JS, а при вводе передавать только маркер ID товара:

```js
// База знаний; тут уже можно гораздо больше ставить, нежели просто цена
let db = [
  {
    cost: 500
  },
  {
    cost: 111
  },
  {
    cost: 894
  }
];

// Простенький делегатор
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('input', function(e){
  let el = document.activeElement;
  if(el.nodeName === 'INPUT' && el.classList.contains('amountInput')) recalculate.call(el);
});

function recalculate() {
  let id = +this.dataset.purchase;
  if(!db[id]) return;
  
  let parent = this.closest('.item'); // Общий предок
  let cost = db[id].cost; // Получаем цену по ID
  
  parent.querySelector('.calcResult').innerHTML = +this.value * cost; // Перемножаем и вставляем в последнюю ячейку
}
```

```css
input[type="number"] {
   width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Стоимость</th>
    <th>Количество</th>
    <th>Итого</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='item'>
    <td>500 гавриков</td>
    <td><input type='number' value='0' data-purchase='0' class='amountInput' /></td>
    <td class='calcResult'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='item'>
    <td>111 гавриков</td>
    <td><input type='number' value='0' data-purchase='1' class='amountInput' /></td>
    <td class='calcResult'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='item'>
    <td>894 гавриков</td>
    <td><input type='number' value='0' data-purchase='2' class='amountInput' /></td>
    <td class='calcResult'>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Благодарю, хоть какой-то рабочий вариант будет. Попробую адаптировать его под свои нужды. Отпишусь о результате.